# Asp.Net Core MVC - Returning edited model not change select that created using SelectTagHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm create a drop down list using this code

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical">
    <select asp-for="Client.ClientCode"
            asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Clients,"ClientCode","Client"))"
            class="form-control" style="width:auto" id="client">
    </select>
</div>
```

Then i edit the model value. But when i returning this model, don't happen anything. The drop down list value not changed.
I have try use ModelState.Clear()

```
 ModelState.Clear();
 return View(model);
```

It does not work. i have try to reload the page using

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

It does not work too. i have try to open page using

```
window.open(url, "_self");
```

It does not work too.
Is there any solution to refresh dropdownlist value ?

Update:
This is the code in view

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Setup(string id)
    {
        var model = HttpContext.Session.GetComplexData<SetupViewModel>("SetupModel");
        if (model == null || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            if (model == null || model.Client.ClientCode != id)
            {
                string clientCode = string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) ? "POI" : id;
                var client = await projectRepository.GetClient(clientCode);
                var ClientList = await projectRepository.GetAllClients();
                var ProjectList = await projectRepository.GetAllProjects(client.ClientCode);

                model = new SetupViewModel()
                {
                    Clients = ClientList.ToList(),
                    Client = client,
                    Projects = ProjectList.ToList(),
                };
                HttpContext.Session.SetComplexData("SetupModel", model);
            }
        }

        ModelState.Clear();
        return View(model);
    }
```

This is the model

```
public class SetupViewModel
{
    public Projects Client { get; set; }
    public List<Projects> Clients { get; set; }

    public Projects Project { get; set; }
    public List<Projects> Projects { get; set; }
    public bool ProjectActive { get; set; }

    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

here is the post code in controller

```
try
        {
            Employee employee = await employeeRepository.GetEmployeeByPhoneNumber(((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst(AccountConstant.PhoneNumber).Value);
            var model = HttpContext.Session.GetComplexData<SetupViewModel>("SetupModel");
            foreach (var project in model.Projects)
            {
                project.ClientCode = newModel.Client.ClientCode;
                project.Client = newModel.Client.Client;
                await projectRepository.Update(project, employee);
            }
            model.Client.Client = newModel.Client.Client;
            model.Client.ClientCode = newModel.Client.ClientCode;

            TempData["Messages"] = "Edit client information has been successful.";
            HttpContext.Session.SetComplexData("SetupModel", model);
            return RedirectToAction("Setup", "Home");
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetComplexData("Error", new ErrorViewModel() { ErrorMessage = exc.ToString() });
            return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
        }
```

Hope this update useful.

Comment: Debug the Code to see if `model` has expected values.

Comment: We need more information about the view model and how you declare it on the view, how you setup the form, etc.

Comment: Sorry, i have updated the code.

Comment: Please try to add some debuggers in the Setup Get and Post method, then steps by steps to debug the code, whether you could get the dropdownlist selected value in the Post method? Besides, from your code, it seems that after updating the data successful, it will return to the Setup Get method, in this method, you could check the returned model, whether the data is correct (I suppose perhaps the issue is related this part of code, if you can't get data from the session, the model will be null, then, it will use the initial data).